# Reference for a hitting time (of a continuous SP) which is not a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I need a book reference for an example of a hitting time defined by a continuous stochastic process which is not a stopping time. I would be thankful for any recommendation!